# Why is my Tailwind CSS toggle button invisible in dark mode?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

```
        <button
        aria-label="Toggle Dark Mode"
        type="button"
        className="lg:inline-flex lg:w-40 md:w-screen p-3 h-12 w-12 order-2 md:order-3"
        onClick={() => setTheme(theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')}></button>
```

This is the code I used for the button. The button is where it should be and it works but it is not visible.

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the background color of the button, or adding some text between the tags to see if that makes it visible?

Answer (score 2):

I made a code sandbox for you: works fine.

probably the element has no width/height due to the fact that it has nothing in it.

(the button is empty)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {useState} from 'react'

const Home = () => {

    const [Theme, setTheme] = useState("light")

  return (
    <>

      <p>Theme is ____ {Theme}</p>

      <button
        aria-label="Toggle Dark Mode"
        type="button"
        className="lg:inline-flex lg:w-40 md:w-screen p-3 h-12 w-12 order-2 md:order-3"
        onClick={() => setTheme(Theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')}>
        press
        
        </button>
    </>
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('App started');

    return <Home/>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: Normally there's padding on a [Tailwind button](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/components/buttons). It should be visible even without text.

Comment: indeed it should. might be some kind of problem with the code's structure